# .htaccess удалён, но воздействие осталось

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Я настроил .htaccess и он прекрасно работал. Но это был лишь тест и я решил закончить его и удалил .htaccess, но его влияние осталось. Файлов в директории нет, но на определенную папку он продолжает влиять. Что делать?

Я нажимаю сюда

> [image: Я нажимаю сюда]

и вместо папки у меня

> [image: и вместо папки у меня]

Comment: Мало подробностей этой мистической загадки. Как влияет? Какая папка? Какой файл пытаетесь открыть?

Comment: Зовите экзорцистов

Comment: Я нажимаю сюда https://prnt.sc/p8eeei
и вместо папки у меня https://prnt.sc/p8eeon

Comment: Судя по скриншотам - у Вас windows. Попробуйте восстановить .htaccess из корзины и добавить его сюда. Возможно, Вам смогут помочь. Если поймут, конечно, что же именно Вы наворотили, что апач при попытке зайти в каталог "JS+PHP" вдруг и внезапно перекидывает Вас из корня сайта на URL, содержащий имя диска с двоеточием...

Comment: Комп перезагрузить пробовал? Или хотя бы сервер перезапустить.